# Reverse voltage parameter Vr in constant current regulators

Tags: current, diodes, datasheet, reverse

I don't quite understand the meaning of the reverse voltage (Vr) parameter of constant current sources.

For example the [Diodes Incorporated BCR401UW6.](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/BCR401UW6.pdf)

Suppose that at the OUT output of the IC there is a capacitor that is charging and reaches its maximum charge to the same input voltage. If I disconnect the input power supply suddenly, does it mean that I will have an inverse voltage Vr between the output and the input?

If this is so, would it be sufficient to place a diode on the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you likely would violate the reverse voltage spec in that situation.

Although "maximum reverse voltage between all terminals" (from the datasheet) isn't the most technical description one could imagine, it basically just means the maximum voltage that is allowed in opposition to the normal operating current flow, i.e. the maximum voltage from GND to OUT, or from OUT to REXT, etc.

Putting a diode on the output should solve your issue as long as the leakage current isnt too high.